# Portable Maven for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, portable

Can anyone recommend a portable [Maven](https://maven.apache.org) that is gratis and works in Windows 7 and above?

Portable Maven will come as a zip file and can be extract to a thumb drive, or a external hard disk. The end-user can bring the thumb drive or external hard disk to another computer and it will run, without the need to connect to the Internet to download any files.